# Can I get actual object from string form of object ("oracle.sql.CLOB@7b8ebb59")?? Is it possible to get actual Object by any chance?

Tags: java, object

Can I get actual object from string form of object ("oracle.sql.CLOB@7b8ebb59")? Is it possible to get actual Object by any chance?

Comment: No. That is not possible from the `String`.

Comment: Depends on wheter it has been garbage collected in the meantime and if you have access to the jvm internal apis that allow you to iterate over all instantiated objects. Then you would have to call `toString` of every instance and compare this to that string. I don't know which jvm internal apis exist for such things.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the text, before the @ is the class name. But that does not include the package name. Two classes in different packages could have the same name, so the text can not uniquely identify even the class of the object in some cases. The number after the @ is the hash code of the object. As two objects can have the same hash code even if they are of the same class, the text can not uniquely identify an object in all cases.

If the text does not uniquely identify an object, it can not be used to retrieve the object.

Comment: My concern with this string is whether we can even get the object from it. I understand it doesn't guarantee uniqueness.